# How do I reduce code duplication with nested 'if' statements?

Tags: f#

let's consider this code:

```
let getBuildDate (assembly: Assembly) : DateTime option =

    let buildVersionMetadataPrefix = "+build"
    let attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()

    if attribute <> null && attribute.InformationalVersion <> null then
        let value = attribute.InformationalVersion
        let index = value.IndexOf(buildVersionMetadataPrefix)
        if index > 0 then
            let value = value.Substring(index + buildVersionMetadataPrefix.Length)
            let success, timestamp = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
            if success then
                Some timestamp
            else
                None
        else
            None
    else
        None
```

Is there a way to get rid of all the 'else None' statements to have only one?

On one side, I can imagine that for some people the code is more clear with all the None statements spelled out, but on the other side, coming from the C world, I see it as clutter that reduces readability.

There are many cases where you need a series of conditions to be met and all the failed cases go to one place.

If I have a list of conditions that depend on each others' success, how can I make a concise short exit without duplication.

Comment: Isn't a computation builder an option here? One example: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-intro/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers show how to do this using more sophisticated functional programming methods, like using computation expressions or `option` values. Those are definitely useful and make sense if this is something that you are doing in many places throughout your system.

However, if you just want a simple way to change the code so that the control flow is more clear (without making it more clever), I would negate the conditions. Previously, you had:

```
if something then 
  moreStuff()
  Some result
else
  None
```

You can rewrite this by returning `None` if `not something`. I think the F# coding convention in this case also allows you to remove the indentation, so it looks more like imperative early return:

```
if not something then None else
moreStuff()
Some result
```

With this, you can write your original function as follows - without any extra clever tricks:

```
let getBuildDate (assembly: Assembly) : DateTime option =

    let buildVersionMetadataPrefix = "+build"
    let attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()

    if attribute = null || attribute.InformationalVersion = null then None else
    let value = attribute.InformationalVersion
    let index = value.IndexOf(buildVersionMetadataPrefix)
    if index <= 0 then None else
    let value = value.Substring(index + buildVersionMetadataPrefix.Length)
    let success, timestamp = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
    if not success then None else
    Some timestamp
```

Comment: The "without any extra clever tricks" code just hides the indentation by not indenting properly. The intent seemed to be to reduce the amount of Nones ("how can I make a concise short exit without duplication") rather than to keep the number the same and hide the indentation.

Answer (score 10):

Another approach might be to use the `Option` functions - each of these steps will effectively short circuit if the input from the previous step is `None`.

```ml
let getBuildDate (assembly: Assembly) : DateTime option =    
    let tryDate value =
         match DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None) with
         | true, date -> Some date
         | false, _ -> None

    let buildVersionMetadataPrefix = "+build"
    let attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()

    Option.ofObj attribute
    |> Option.bind (fun attr -> Option.ofObj attr.InformationalVersion)
    |> Option.map (fun infVer -> infVer, infVer.IndexOf buildVersionMetadataPrefix)
    |> Option.filter (fun (_, index) -> index > 0)
    |> Option.map (fun (infVer, index) -> infVer.Substring(index + buildVersionMetadataPrefix.Length))
    |> Option.bind tryDate
```

Whether this is 'better' is arguable - and definitely a matter of opinion!

Answer (score 3):

A readable approach might be use a computation expression builder for `Option`.

```
type OptionBuilder() =
    member _.Return v = Some v
    member _.Zero () = None
    member _.Bind(v, f) = Option.bind f v
    member _.ReturnFrom o = o

let opt = OptionBuilder()
```

You can simulate an imperative style of `if-then-return`.

```
let condition num = num % 2 = 0

let result = opt {
    if condition 2 then 
        if condition 4 then 
            if condition 6 then 
                return 10
}
```

Rewriting your example:

```
let getBuildDate (assembly: Assembly) : DateTime option = opt {

    let buildVersionMetadataPrefix = "+build"
    let attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()

    if attribute <> null && attribute.InformationalVersion <> null then
        let value = attribute.InformationalVersion
        let index = value.IndexOf(buildVersionMetadataPrefix)
        if index > 0 then
            let value = value.Substring(index + buildVersionMetadataPrefix.Length)
            let success, timestamp = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
            if success then
                return timestamp
}
```

No more `None`.

Answer (score 1):

```
open System
open System.Reflection
open System.Globalization

let inline guard cond next = if cond then next () else None

let getBuildDate (assembly: Assembly) : DateTime option =
    let buildVersionMetadataPrefix = "+build"
    let attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>()

    guard (attribute <> null && attribute.InformationalVersion <> null) <| fun _ ->
    let value = attribute.InformationalVersion
    let index = value.IndexOf(buildVersionMetadataPrefix)
    guard (index > 0) <| fun _ ->
    let value = value.Substring(index + buildVersionMetadataPrefix.Length)
    let success, timestamp = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None)
    guard success <| fun _ ->
    Some timestamp
```

If you can stomach the inelegance of having to write `<| fun _ ->` on every `guard`, this is an option worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [`Result<TSuccess, TError>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/results). It is very structuring - making the code rigid and flat - and makes it possible to provide detailed error information for the step that possible fails. It's a little more code, but IMO more readable and maintainable:

```
let getBuildDate (assembly: Assembly) : Result<DateTime, string> = 

    let buildVersionMetadataPrefix = "+build"

    let extractAttribute (assem: Assembly) = 
        match assem.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>() with
        | attrib when attrib <> null -> Ok attrib
        | _ -> Error "No attribute found"

    let extractDateString (attrib: AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute) =
        match attrib.InformationalVersion.IndexOf (buildVersionMetadataPrefix) with
        | x when x > 0 -> Ok (attrib.InformationalVersion.Substring (x + buildVersionMetadataPrefix.Length))
        | _ -> Error "Metadata prefix not found"

    let toDateTime dateString =
        match DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None) with
        | true, timeStamp -> Ok timeStamp
        | false, _ -> Error "Invalid date time format"

    extractAttribute assembly
    |> Result.bind extractDateString
    |> Result.bind toDateTime
```

---

**Usage**

```
let optBuildDate = getBuildDate (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
match optBuildDate with
| Ok date -> printfn "%A" date
| Error msg -> printfn "ERROR: %s" msg
```

Comment: in a case like posted above, this would be overkill as I either get the data, or not, for reasons outside of the user's control. But in general, I like this approach. I really need to start learning about monads in F# :) thanks for the answer.

Comment: Railway Oriented Programming : https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/recipe-part2/

Answer (score 0):

There is an approach that I really love which is the use of an array in certain scenarios.

Example:

Instead of using something like:

```js
    if (grade >= 90) {
        scale = "A";
    } else if (grade >= 80) {
        scale = "B";
    } else if (grade >= 70) {
        scale = "C";
    } else if (grade >= 60) {
        scale = "D";
    } else {
        scale = "F";
    }
```

Use an array like:

```js
function calculate(scores) {
    var grade, scale;

    let sum = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        sum += scores[i];
    }

    grade = sum / scores.length;
    scale = {
        [90 <= grade && grade <= 100]: "O",
        [80 <= grade && grade < 90]: "E",
        [70 <= grade && grade < 80]: "A",
        [55 <= grade && grade < 70]: "P",
        [40 <= grade && grade < 55]: "D",
        [grade < 40]: "T"
    };
    console.log(scale.true);
}
```

In python could be like:

```py
def calculate(scores: list) -> str:
    grade = sum(scores) / len(scores)
    print(grade)
    scale = {90 <= grade <= 100: "O", 80 <=
                grade < 90: "E", 70 <= grade < 80: "A",
                55 <= grade < 70: "P", 40 <= grade < 55: "D",
                grade < 40: "T"}
    return scale.get(True)
```